# c# after ds.readxml to datagridview how to fire CellEndEdit

Tags: c#, datagridview

have datagridview where are columns 
lenght,width,qty, and readonly column M2 (where is calculated LxWxQ with CellEndEdit event )

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int m2lenght = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
            int m2width = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
            int m2qty = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
            float m2row = m2lenght * m2width * m2qty / 1000000F;
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value = m2row;
        }
```

Can import xml file (with lenght, width, qty) throught dataset to datagridview.
Import work fine.

```
private void XmlLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("D:\\test.xml");

            foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["Data"].Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0];
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1];
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2];
            }
         }
```

But after import the colummn M2 is without result.
How can i fire the CellEndEdit event on each row??

I try already

```
dataGridView1.Upate();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

but without any change.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `CurrentCell` and then to call `dataGridView1_CellEndEdit`:

```
private void XmlLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("D:\\test.xml");

            foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["Data"].Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();     
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0];    
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1]; 
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2];
                dateGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dateGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0];
                dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(this, null);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but just on the first row, all other rows are witohut result

Comment: so you can trigger it every cell update. I aligned my answer.

Comment: Still just only the first row is calculated. It enought that i run the BeginEdit and EndEdit on last item[2]; column. But how to do on every inserted row?

Comment: I understand the problem, you are using CurrentRow filed in the event handler. See my last update.